# XStream implicit configouration

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I am working with XML like:

```
<localMSZ>
    <territories>
        <codeOKTMO>str1</codeOKTMO>
        <codeOKTMO>str2</codeOKTMO>
    </territories>
</localMSZ>
```

In Java code I have class `LocalMSZ` which have `List` of `String` like:

```
class LocalMSZ {
    List<String> territories;
}
```

I doesn't understand how I should post annotation in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your mapping class: it lacks the structure and annotations needed for this.  It should work with this:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamConverter;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamImplicit;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.extended.ToAttributedValueConverter;

@XStreamAlias("localMSZ")
public class LocalMSZ {

    private Territories territories = new Territories();

    public Territories getTerritories() {
        return territories;
    }

    public void setTerritories(Territories territories) {
        this.territories = territories;
    }

    @XStreamAlias("codeOKTMO")
    @XStreamConverter(value = ToAttributedValueConverter.class, strings = { "value" })
    public static class Code {
        private String value;

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }


    }

    @XStreamAlias("territories")
    public static class Territories {
        // This one maps the sequence of <codeOKTMO> tags
        @XStreamImplicit
        private List<Code> codes = new LinkedList<Code>();

        public List<Code> getCodes() {
            return codes;
        }

        public void setCodes(List<Code> codes) {
            this.codes = codes;
        }


    }
}
```

Remember also when you write your main method to process the annotations of LocalMSZ

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.processAnnotations(LocalMSZ.class);
...
```